# How to replicate this table in GTK+3

Tags: gtk, gtk3, glade

I am interested in how can I replicate the table that looks like on picture under "Known Media Players". I looked into .glade file of PulseAudio plugin and it seems like it was implemented using GtkTable which was deprecated in favour of GtkGrid. How can I replicate the table layout and the "header" of the table using GtkGrid?

[image: PulseAudio Xfce4 panel plugin configuration screen made in GTK+2]

Comment: Looking at the [glade file](https://git.xfce.org/panel-plugins/xfce4-pulseaudio-plugin/tree/panel-plugin/pulseaudio-dialog.glade) of PA-plugin, it has been ported to GtkGrid since then.

Comment: Well, sucks I did not notice that. Thanks for the link. Seems like the new version is using GtkTreeView which seems to be working in that case, I'll try to implement that in my project to see how it works.